# Add click event to render props?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Parent component which includes a Child component and passes it some render props.

```
const Parent = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <Child>
                Text that I want
            </Child>
        </div>
    )
}

class Child extends React.Component{
    handleClick() {
        console.log('Hi')
    }
    render() {
        return(
            {this.props.children}
        )
    }
}
```

How can I make it so when the render props content "Text that I want" is clicked the Child's handleClick function is executed?

Comment: what would you want to do if you render multiple elements as children to Child component

Comment: I wont need to do that. My actual use case is I have a mutation in Apollo that I need to use in different components. I will only ever render one Component within Child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply make use of `React.cloneElement` if `this.props.children` is anything other than a string or else wrap the text within span and attach the handler to it

```
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <Child>
        Text that I want
      </Child>
    </div>
  )
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Hi')
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.children)
    if(typeof this.props.children === 'string') {
      return <span onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.children}</span>
    }
    return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
      onClick: this.handleClick
    });
  }
}
```

**[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7l3k2nqvz)**

Answer (score 1):

Wrap children in `Child` component with an element and pass it your event handler:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div onClick={() => this.handleClick()}> 
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: But say I pass a button rather than just text? Then I would like the click event on the button not a containing div.

Comment: @Evans then why not handle event from the parent component and then pass result (whatever it is) to the child component?

Comment: My requirement is that the "handleClick" function can be shared between different components. Obviously in my actual code "handleClick" is a lot more complicated.

Comment: @Evans generally when you click, it will update the state and components just render that state (you don't need handlers in each component). However if you want to react to events from multiple sources, you could look for some publish/subscribe event library

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
class Child extends React.Component{
    handleClick() {
        console.log('Hi')
    }
    render() {
        // pass click handler as an argument to function
        return this.props.children(this.handleClick.bind(this));
    }
}

const Parent = () => (
    <div>
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <Child>
         // use click handle passed as argument
         {clickHandler => <p onClick={clickHandler}>Text that I want</p>}
       </Child>
    </div>
)
```

because you can't have any events coming from a bare text you need a tag like `p` to attach it.